# jQuery UI - Selectable Widget - How to disable multi select?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

In jquery ui selectable widget, I noticed that you can select more than one item by holding ctrl (or by dragging a box), but how do you disable multi selecting. I only want to be able to select 1 at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is a fairly crude implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/rtRjK/

Basically, when an element is selected, first unselect the all its siblings that have been selected - this handles ctrl-clicks. Next, iterate over the siblings that are selecting and unselect them - this handles drags. As a consequence, dragging always takes the element with largest y-coordinate.

You can also roll your own selectable widget. I removed the ctrl key reference and `_mouseDrag` function from `$.ui.selectable`: http://jsfiddle.net/zFFXc/

Comment: The singleselectable plug-in is a whole lot cleaner. Up-voted this answer based on the "You can also..." portion as all the other answers I've read are hacky and not clean and professional UI. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myList li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

selectable, single-select, with keyboard

```
//after load
$(function() {

    // make <ol id=lista> selectable (jquery UI)
    $("#lista").selectable();
    $("#lista").children(":first-child").addClass("selected"); //select first

    $(document).keydown(function(ev) { //con keyboard

        var actual = $(".selected");
        switch (ev.keyCode) {

            case 13: // User pressed "enter" key
                actual.dblclick();
                ev.preventDefault();
                break;

            case 38: // User pressed "up" arrow
                actual.prev().click();
                ev.preventDefault();
                break;

            case 40: // User pressed "down" arrow
                actual.next().click();
                ev.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    }); //end keydown

    //single select
    $("#lista li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });

}); // end $(fn...
```